# How to disable secure url for admin

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, redirect, ssl, access

I have installed ssl certificate , but https is still not working, so I would like to disable secure url for admin to work in backend. 
I have updated the mg_core_config_data table for the path secure url to http://mydomain.com. And use secure urls in admin to 0. I have reindexed using the php indexer.php reindexall inside the shell folder. I have emptied the var/cache folder too. What am I missing ?

Comment: Hello, did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable secure url for admin, you need to set the path `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` value to 0 (or delete the record).

Comment: I have set it to 0 already

Comment: Make sure that there's no other records for different scopes. Also make sure that web server doesn't have forced redirects.

Comment: I have deleted that row itself. How to stop forced redirects ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the base unsecure url in admin. You may have mentioned as https://mydomain.com

update mg_core_config_data table for the path unsecure url with http://mydomain.com